# Error IndexOutBoundsExceptional recorrer datos en ArrayList Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist

En mi aplicación estoy generando 6 números aleatorios que no se repiten y que se guardan en una ArrayList. El problema viene que al recorrer dicho ArrayList mediante un for me da error de IndexOutOfBoundsException. Creo que no hay nada raro, simplemente estoy recorriendo un ArrayList con un for y creo que esta es la forma correcta, pero me da este error. Quisiera saber por qué el valor i está alcanzando el valor 6 si se supone que ahí ya está fuera de la lista. Otra cosa que he notado es que si le pongo .size a listRandom1 me da error.

```
    for(i in listRandom1){
        println(listRandom1[i])
    }
```

El error

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6

Comment: no sé kotlin, pero los arrays son base cero, tu variable i, que valor tiene en un principio? si es 1, al buscar la posición 6, va a darte error

Comment: El valor que se le está asignando a `i` no es el índice sino el valor en sí que tiene el array en dicho índice. Estás recorriendo el array valor por valor en orden. Si quieres que se le asigne a `i` el valor del índice entonces hazlo así: `for (i in listRandom1.indices) { ... }`.

Comment: Ahora sí, todo correcto. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un malentendido, si deseas obtener los elementos de una lista y deseas usar un `for` de esta forma:

```
   for(i in listRandom1){
      ...
   }
```

el valor de `i` es el elemento de la lista, no el indice.

Por lo tanto puedes imprimir los elementos dentro de la lista, lo debes realizar de esta forma que es la correcta:

```
  for(elemento in listRandom1){
        println(elemento)
   }
```

---

Si deseas usar los indices para imprimir los elementos dentro de la lista usa `listRandom1.indices` para obtener el indice y haces la referencia de los elemento usando su indice, pero esto no es recomendable ya que es una forma màs lenta de obtener los elementos.

```
  for (i in listRandom1.indices) {
      println(listRandom1[i])
  }
```

---

Si deseas usar la medida del array para iterar y obtener los valores dentro del array puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
 for (i in 0..listRandom1.size - 1) {
        println(listRandom1[i])
    }
```

Comment: Genial así sí funciona. No sé si es posible, pero recuerdo haber usado alguna vez listRandom.size, ¿esto es posible? Aun que me daba error cuando probé ayer.

Comment: @PacoPepe , agregue como puedes realizarlo usando la medida del array (.size).